# error: unknown type name 'intptr_t'

Tags: c, mingw, intptr

I am receiving this error while compiling a C program in MinGW. As far as I know, I thought 'intptr_t' was a type in the C99 standard. Am I not including a file?

Comment: In my case, it was a wrong msys2 setup. I had success with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to include `stdint.h`.

Note that `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are indeed C99 types but they are optional.